# Small knock ($\delta$) on rotating Pendulum in Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, perturbation-theory

Following Setup:

There is a Pendulum swinging around a vertical axis, with angles $\varphi$ for rotation, and $\theta$ for the incline compared to the horizontal axis. The mass is $m$ and the length is $\ell =const.$

[image: Pendulum]

(maybe required pre-knowledge):

The lagrangian is
$$
L=\frac{1}{2}m(\ell^2\dot{\theta}^2+\ell^2\sin^2{(\theta)}\dot{\varphi}^2)-mgl(1-\cos{\theta})
$$

solving the lagrangian for $\theta$

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}\right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} = 0 
$$
$$
\ddot{\theta}+\frac{g}{\ell}\sin{\theta}-\frac{1}{2}\sin{(2\theta)}\dot{\varphi}^2 = 0
$$
With $\varphi = \varphi_0$ and $\dot{\varphi}=0$ you get the normal differential equation for a swinging pendulum:
$$
\ddot{\theta}+\frac{g}{\ell}\sin{\theta}-\frac{1}{2}\sin{(2\theta)}\dot{\varphi}^2 = 0
$$
$$
\ddot{\theta}+\frac{g}{\ell}\sin{\theta}-0 = 0
$$
$$
\ddot{\theta}+\frac{g}{\ell}\sin{\theta} = 0
$$
Now using $\theta=\theta_0$ and $\dot{\theta}=0 \forall{t}$ find the frequency of Rotation by Integrating $\dot{\varphi}$ for one period
$$
\frac{g}{\ell}\sin{\theta_0}-\frac{1}{2}\sin{(2\theta_0)}\dot{\varphi}^2 = 0
$$
$$
\dot{\varphi}=\sqrt{\frac{2g\sin{\theta_0}}{\ell\sin{(2\theta_0)}}} = \sqrt{\frac{g}{\ell\cos{\theta_0}}}
$$
$$
\int\dot{\varphi}dt=2\pi
$$
$$
\sqrt{\frac{g}{\ell\cos{\theta_0}}}t=2\pi \rightarrow t=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\frac{g}{\ell\cos{\theta_o}}}}
$$

Problems:

1. If we consider an infinitesimally small knock in the direction of $\theta$, with $\theta=\theta_0+\delta$ and $\dot{\theta}=0$, show that the differential equation for $\delta$ is:
   $$
   \ddot{\delta}+\frac{g}{l}\sin{(\theta_0+\delta)}-\frac{g}{l}\frac{\sin^4{\theta_0}}{\cos{\theta_0}}\frac{\cos{(\theta_0+\delta)}}{\sin^3{(\theta_0+\delta)}} = 0
   $$
2. Because $\delta$ is infinitesimal, expand (Taylor-Expansion) the previous Formula to the first degree in $\delta$

I have no idea how to tackle either problem. for the 1st I would have just inserted $\theta$ inside the equation of motion for $\theta$, however that would obviously not get me to the correct formula, and for the Taylor Expansion I don't even know what to expand, because usually you'd do an expansion for a function (At least until now that's all I've seen), and I don't see a function here. Any help would be very appreciated

Addendum:

If I were to replace $\theta$ with $\theta_0+\delta$ in the Lagrangian it would be

$$
L = \frac{1}{2}m\ell^2\sin^2{(\theta_0+\delta)}-mg\ell(1-\cos{(\theta_0+\delta)})
$$
now using the Lagrange-Euler formula, because there is no $\dot{\delta}$ you can only use $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\delta}$
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial\delta} = \frac{1}{2}m\ell^2\sin{(2\theta_0+2\delta)}\dot{\varphi}^2+mg\ell^2\sin{(\theta_0+\delta)} = 0
$$

though I don't know how that would help me. Maybe I just did something wrong?

Comment: Re “just inserted”: which “previous formula”? Are you thinking of putting $\theta_0+\delta$ into the equation of motion directly, or have you tried putting $\theta_0+\delta$ in the Lagrangian and solving the Euler-Lagrange equations for $\delta$?

Comment: I was thinking of putting $\theta_0+\delta$ into the equation of motion for $\theta$, should I be putting it into the Lagrangian and then do $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\delta}})-\frac{\partial L}{\partial \delta}$? I didn't even consider that. We're at the very beginning of Lagrangian mechanics, this is our first assignment involving it, so sorry if what I'm saying may be nonsensical.

Comment: It’s not nonsense. If you’re rusty on your trig identities for sums of angles, you’re going to be annoyed getting $\delta$ alone enough to differentiate it. If that solves your problem, consider writing a self-answer (keeping in mind that we answer the conceptual parts of homework-like questions). If it doesn’t, please edit your question to clarify why not.

Comment: The trig identities aren't the hard part, I can Google them or look them up on Wolfram Alpha.
I do have issues getting to the equation of motion in the first place though. If you just swap $\theta$ for $\theta_0 + \delta$ in the Lagrangian and then try to do the Lagrange Euler equation you'd only actually be getting a result for $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\delta}$, if I see correctly... and that alone doesn't get me to the required form, a whole $\ddot{\delta}$ would be missing after all, no matter what the other terms say.
Are you confident that this is the right method or is it a guess?

Comment: In 1. you got $~\ddot\delta=f(\delta)~$ taking the first order Taylor- Expansion means  $~\ddot\delta_l=f(0)+\frac{d f}{d \delta}\bigg|_{\delta=0}\,\delta$

Comment: Oh, and with that I'm getting a much easier Differential Equation if I see that right? Is that what Taylor Expansions are usually used for? We've never done any so this is the first time I see this, but it does make sense.